# Using an array as hovertemplate in a Plotly Sankey plot

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I want to use a Sankey plot where the hover info is customized on a per node basis. I expected to be able to use the hovertemplate with a list of strings. Unfortunately, this leads to no hover info shown at all.

I used the [basic Sankey example](https://plotly.com/javascript/sankey-diagram/#basic-sankey-diagram) from the documentation and added a new argument called hovertemplate:

```
var data = {
  type: "sankey",
  orientation: "h",
  node: {
    pad: 15,
    thickness: 30,
    line: {
      color: "black",
      width: 0.5,
    },
    label: ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],
    color: ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"],
    hovertemplate: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],  \\ This is the only difference to the docs
  },

  link: {
    source: [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3],
    target: [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
    value: [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2],
  },
};

var data = [data];

var layout = {
  title: "Basic Sankey",
  font: {
    size: 10,
  },
};

Plotly.react("myDiv", data, layout);
```

I expected this to show the respective letters as the hover info. Unfortunately, no hover info is shown at all.

As a short sanity check, I replaced the array with a simple string `"a"` and this leads to expected result of showing only `a` on hover for all nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now (August 2023), contrary to what the [documentation](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/sankey/#sankey-node-hovertemplate) says, setting an array of strings as `hovertemplate` doesn't work with sankey nodes/links (it doesn't work either with heatmaps and likely many other trace types. It does work though with scatter and bar traces).

What you can do instead is adding [`customdata`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/sankey/#sankey-node-customdata), which you can then refer to in `hovertemplate` with `'%{customdata}'`.

> `customdata` - Assigns extra data each datum. This may be useful when
> listening to hover, click and selection events.

```
var data = {
  type: "sankey",
  orientation: "h",
  node: {
    pad: 15,
    thickness: 30,
    line: {
      color: "black",
      width: 0.5,
    },
    label: ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],
    color: ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"],
    customdata: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], 
    hovertemplate: '%{customdata}'
  },

  link: {
    source: [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3],
    target: [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
    value: [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2],
  },
};

var data = [data];

var layout = {
  title: "Basic Sankey",
  font: {
    size: 10,
  },
};

Plotly.react("myDiv", data, layout);
```

Note that you can also add customdata to the links and set their hovertemplate as well, just like for the nodes.

Comment: Ah, that's a smart idea to use customdata and set it like this. Thanks a lot! But just for my understanding: Does this means that it's not possible to use an array for hovertemplate contrary to what [the docs](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/sankey/#sankey-node-hovertemplate) say?

Comment: Yes for now it seems to. Either the doc (which is the same for every trace type regarding hovertemplate) should be fixed, or the hovertemplate feature should be fixed for those types that don't support arrays. It might be worth [opening an issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues).